# Failure to load libraries in virtual environment in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

I have installed virtual environment for my project in PyCharm (through PyCharm->Settings->Project->Python Interpreter). Then I installed NumPy and SciPy packages on this interpreter (in the same place). Nevertheless, when trying to import NumPy I get failure. Looking into the interpreter paths I see the venv site-packages dir, but when printing sys.paths in the code I do not see this dir in the path.
Tried the same with conda venv and experienced the same behavior.
Would appreciate any help!
Thanks

Comment: Did you activate the virutal environment before you installed the packages?  https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#activating-a-virtual-environment may help?

Comment: I'm working though pycharm (2020) and from what I understood there is no need to activate the venv when working through pycharm. am I missing something?